# Delphi> Can I store a bitmap's data in my unit (not the dfm)?

Tags: delphi, components

I have a class declared in a unit, and it needs to work with a specific bitmap.
It is declared in the DFM of my test unit like this:

```
  object ImgTop: TImage
    Left = 208
    Top = 568
    Width = 777
    Height = 41
    Picture.Data = {
      0A544A504547496D616765A1CF0000FFD8FFE000104A46494600010101025802
      [truncated]
      };
```

But in my final unit I won't be having a dfm. 
So is there a way I can declare it in my unit?

===

Thanks, I seem to have it working now, pitty about the size limitations on bitmaps :(
Here's what I did:

In my folder are these files:

```
imgleft.bmp
imgtop.bmp
```

This is my resource file called ScanOCRres.rc:

```
1 RT_BITMAP "imgtop.bmp"
2 RT_BITMAP "imgleft.bmp"
```

I have set it to automatically execute with C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi 7\bin\brcc32.exe

It generated the file

```
ScanOCRres.RES
```

In my unit I have
implementation

```
{$R *.dfm}
{$R ScanOCRres.RES}
```

And here's my code:

```
var
  abmp : TBitmap;
begin
  abmp := TBitmap.create;
  abmp.LoadFromResourceID(SysInit.HInstance, 1);
  abmp.free;
end;
```

I get this error message on the LoadFromResourceID line:

Project Project1.exe raised exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 0040A2C8 in module 'Project1.exe'. **Read of address 00000001**'

Comment: Does the exception address change if you try to load resource 2 instead? Try passing 0 instead of SysInit.HInstance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *could* put it in your code, but it wouldn't be very convenient to work with. Declare an array of bytes and define each byte of your image. Good luck editing it. To load it, I'd wrap the byte array into a `TMemoryStream` and then use [`LoadFromStream`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Graphics.TBitmap.LoadFromStream).

A better way is to store the image in a *resource*. Write a resource script file like this:

```
1 RT_BITMAP "foo.bmp"
```

Add that *.rc* file to your Delphi project, and it will automatically be linked to your program. At run time, load the image with [`TBitmap.LoadFromResourceId`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Graphics.TBitmap.LoadFromResourceID):

```
var
  b: TBitmap;
begin
  b := TBitmap.Create;
  b.LoadFromResourceId(SysInit.HInstance, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks RobCan.
Can you please clarify why you say RT_BITMAP instead of BMP, and instead of '1' can I put 'IMGTOP' and then call     .LoadFromResourceName(hInstance, 'IMGTOP'); ?? Also, should I put {$R MyResource.RES} or {$R *.RES}??

Comment: In $R directive "*" means "the same file name as the unit name"... so you can use {$R *.res} if your res have the same file name of your unit.  You can also use a full file name with $R, so you can use {$R AnyFileName.res} if you find it more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I made this. It's crude but it works. Converts component's picture to picture.data as a string.

```js
Procedure ImgToText(Com : TComponent; var str : AnsiString);
var i,c : integer;
s : tmemorystream;
b : byte;
t : array[0..3] of char;
ch : char;
begin
 s := tmemorystream.Create;
 s.WriteComponent(com);
 s.Position := 0;
 c := 0;
 repeat
  s.Read(ch,1);
  if ch = '.' then
  begin
   s.Read(t,4);
   if t = 'Data' then
    c := s.Position+5;
  end;
 until c <> 0;
 s.Position := c;
 str := '';
 i := c;
 c := 0;
 repeat
  s.ReadBuffer(b,1);
  str := str+inttohex(b,2);
  c := c+2;
  if c >= 64 then
  begin
   str := str+#13+#10;
   c := 0;
  end;
  i := i+1;
 until i = s.Size-2;
 s.Free;
end;
```